# TFS 2017 Permission management seems to be least Privledged?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

**Background**
I'm working on implementing Agile permissions along with Code permissions for a TFS project.  There will be multiple teams in this project, we currently have 3 but will grow.  I am set up with Project Admin rights.

**Area Permissions**
At the root TFS Area Project Admins have the ability to create, delete and edit this node rights.  Team members do not.

**Problem**
When I add my self to one of the teams groups I'm no longer able to delete items from this node even though I am a Project Admin.  That means I can never be a part of the teams?  This will hurt me in capacity planning amongst other areas where I work on tasks when not administrating the project.

Am I missing something?  Is there a setting to allow Most Privileged or something that allows me to be a team member and still perform administration of the project?

Comment: What is the Project Admins permission on the Nodes? You can "deny" project administrators from doing actions.

Comment: @DaveShaw Project Admin Security has Allow for the top three perms on the Area.  Create, Delete and Edit. I believe I found a reference to the same issue here:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fd7ae6b9-c684-40ae-aa06-025c627522ba/have-a-custom-permission-in-tfs-20172?forum=tfsgeneral It says if you are a member of two groups and one group has deny set then you are denied, even though I'm project admin.  That is rather restricting if that is the case because I can't be on a team as a person who has more permissions than the team members because I will lose those permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use explicit Deny permissions -- an explicit Deny overrides explicit Allows. "Not Set" is what you're looking to use -- that means "deny, unless otherwise allowed".

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that "**Deny**" will override any other permissions. **Deny** always wins.

you can do 2 things

- Remove ADMIN from the team group. An admin account shouldn't need to
  be a member of a contributors group as admin is a superset of the
  permissions given to contributors.
- If for some reason you cannot remove the account from this group then
  change the permissions. TFS permissions have 3 states. `Allow`, `not set`, `Deny`.

  As the deny is causing the issue, then change the
  permissions to "`not set`" this will still prevent members of the
  contributors group from being able to manage permissions, but will
  stop overriding the admin users permissions

Comment: Yes the "Not Set" approach is what we need.  We have people who wear many hats at times and those people can possibly be on a team that is either checking in code or working UserStories.  I'm still getting my feet wet here and I see if the user isn't on the team you can't add them in capacity.  I'm not sure what would be effected outside of using the Capacity functions?

Comment: @gperrego  So, you have resolved the original permission issue by above solutions, right? Then you could Accept it as an Answer, This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Comment: Sorry I up voted instead of Accepting, all set now.  Thanks for the help.